# Processor compatibility with IMDT and Intel Optane DC P4800X

Tags: ssd, optane

I bought the following [Intel SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076TCZ3CM) and I want to combine it with IMDT (Intel Memory Drive Technology). From what I understood, the IMDT comes pre-installed with the P4800X drive. On the other side, I've seen different specification between them:

1. [Here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/memory-and-storage/intel-mdt-setup-guide.pdf) (in the last page which has the specification) ,it's written that IMDT is compatible with both Xeon and Intel core. But [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/optane-ssd-dc-p4800x-mdt-brief.html) (Specifications) it's written that the P4800x is compatible with only Xeon processors. Why is it different? Doesn't IMDT come pre-installed with P4800X?
2. [Here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/memory-and-storage/intel-mdt-setup-guide.pdf) (in the last page which has the specification), what do they mean in the capacity section? Doesn't it support the P4800X capacity?

Comment: You have linked to a manual twice.  We have no idea which pages you are referring to.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes sorry, I missed that part. I've edited the question to specify the pages.